# UIPopoverController over UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'd like to programmatically select a row in a table view then present my popover and let the arrow points to the cell.

This code works fine when the table has no scrolling, for scrolling table view the popover arrow is positioned incorrectly.

```
[self.EventsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                                  animated:YES 
                            scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectOffset(cell.frame, 0, cell.frame.size.height + self.EventsTableView.contentOffset) 
                                   inView:self.view      
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft 
                                 animated:YES];
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the cell as the view. Most likely you will want to pass the cell's bounds (cell.bounds, not cell.frame) for the rect.

Comment: Correct, good answer
Simply:
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];

Thank you.

Comment: Still I need to handle invisible rows!

Comment: Do you mean when a cell is scrolled in such a way that it is not visible? In that case you probably want to move it into view with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`.

Answer (score 5):

Above method didn’t seem to work for me when once the user scrolls the list down. Finding the cell position relative to the scrolled amount was the trick.

```
CGRect rect = [tableView convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
    toView:tableView]; 

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
    inView:tableView
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
    animated:YES];
```